# Filter PDF messages in Outlook 2010 standard

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, email-filter

I have an inbox full of messages and would like to flag (or otherwise filter) all messages that have a (or more) PDF attachment.

I tried creating a "Rule", but there seems to be no standard way to do this built-in.

Comment: Your point is the PDF, right? You *can* make rules for 'has attachment'.

Comment: @Aganju right. I saw "has attachment". In fact, I want to filter out all mails that do NOT have a PDF attachment; those are the ones that need attention.

Comment: There is 'Run a Script' in the actions list; that might be a way. But I have no idea how such a script would look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in the search box for Outlook 2010 `ext:pdf` and this site has a ton of ways to play with this search feature [Attachments by extension](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/find-attachments-by-extension-or-contents).  Including `ext:(docx OR pdf)` `ext:(doc NOT docx)` and `ext:(NOT docx) hasattachments:yes`

I think what you need is to search this `ext:(NOT pdf) hasattachments:yes`

Comment: This seems to work in folders of the main account, but not on another (shared) account. Or at least dodgy. `hasattachments` seem to work as expected, `ext` confuses me a little: `NOT pdf` gives me all mails, `pdf` yields no results at all.

Comment: Did you read the whole linked page?  It's really short, the `ext` in `ext:<extension>` as they put it is the file extension that you are looking for, or NOT in those cases.  You need `ext:` in order for it to search specifically for attachment extensions.

Comment: yes I read it, and the exact same search string works in the Inbox, but not on that shared folder. `hasattachments` works, but the `ext` just doesn't.

Comment: Did that end up working for the shared folder?

Comment: No, but I will copy everything local (have to anyway) and then filter. The solution is the one used, so thanks for that.

Comment: Sorry bout the shared folder. I wouldn't think it would be aby different but permissions are a fickle mistress.  Good luck with the email cleanup